# Apppend a list in a list of list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to do a function in haskell. The purpose of the function is to add a list to an existing list of list.

```
[Int] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
```

I wish it would work like :

```
[1] -> [[2],[3]] -> [[2],[3],[1]]
```

I would like to know how I can proceed to do that. There is an existing included function to do that?

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i don't know how to do a "intelligent" function for that case. I meant, i can do a function who can separate the 2 arguments of the list of list like a (b:c) and after [a,b,c] but if i have more thing in my [[Int]], it's impossible.

Comment: Unlike prepending, you cannot efficiently append to a standard list, as it requires copying every element of the original list into the new list. That said, consider how you might use `(++)` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the element `[1]` in a singleton list, and then append the two lists with [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-). So you can implement such function with:

```
addlast :: a -> [a] -> [a]
addlast x ys = ys ++ [x]
```

The `(++)` function however will usually take linear time in the number of elements of the left operand (so `ys`), which makes it computationally expensive. Therefore it is usually better if order does not matter to prepend to a list.

In the [**`extra`** package [Hackage]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra), you can make use of [**`snoc :: [a] -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.1/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:snoc). In that case, this is thus a "flipped" version of `snoc`:

```
import Data.List.Extra(snoc)

addlast :: a -> [a] -> [a]
addlast = flip snoc
```

Comment: oh i was doing that, but without the [] for the first list. Okay, thanks, it's much better like that.